# FATAL EXCEPTION: when building AndEngine sample

Tags: android-studio, andengine

I am using andengine example found here http://www.makethegame.net/android-andengine/how-to-setup-andengine-with-android-studio/

I get an error when I try this method. Do you know why?

I get it around this part in my code:

```
public class DeviceDetailsActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceDetailsActivity";
    public static final String DEVICE_EXTRA = "DEVICE_EXTRA";
    private static long CONNECTION_DELAY = 12000;
    private static long PAIRING_DELAY = 12000;
    private List<UUID> mServices;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Menu mOptionsMenu;
    private IntentFilter mIasIntentFilter;
    private boolean isServiceBound;

    //Ethan add button click

   public void goButtonClicked(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grushgame);
    }
```

**Here it is the error.**

```
11-14 20:42:42.742 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.intel.agm_test_app, PID: 17682
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field ‘org.andengine.engine.Engine org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.mEngine’ on a null object reference
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView.onMeasure(RenderSurfaceView.java:68)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17633)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17633)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5538)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17633)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5538)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17633)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5538)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2689)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17633)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2056)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1407)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1085)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5991)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
11-14 20:42:42.752 17682-17682/com.intel.agm_test_app E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Comment: did you set the engine options ? please share the code for engine options

Comment: Hi Waqas, how to I set the engine options in Android studio? I can paste the file if you tell me where

Comment: please check the link to see how to set engine options. http://www.matim-dev.com/hello-world---basic-example.html